# Effect of time duration in bandpass filtering

Tags: digital-filters

I am new in DSP, but I am trying to process EEG data to decompose into the bands, theta, alpha, and others.

The raw data is processed:

1. Remove the DC offset by subtracting the average value from the entire data channels.
2. High pass filtering.
   Both such as [in](https://emotiv.gitbook.io/emotivpro-v2-0/notes-on-the-data/code-examples).

The using the bandpass function of Matlab it is bandpassed.

```
delta = [0.1 4];
theta = [4 8];
alpha = [8 12];
beta = [12 30];
gamma = [30 45];
bands = [delta; theta; alpha; beta; gamma];
fs = 128; % sampling freq of the EEG

% choosing a segment of data

time = 2 ; % secs
fs = 128;
size_t = fs * time;
sample_filt = af3(1:size_t); %  AF3, an EEG node

% band passing
eeg_bands = {};
for i = 1  : size(bands, 1)
    eeg_bands{i} = bandpass( sample_filt, bands(i,:), fs);
end

% code to plot
```

I performed bandpass for samples of different time duration, however, I saw the time duration changes the amplitudes of bands at the start and end in gamma and beta (high frequency bands).

here, I plot three figures. Figure 1 of long 5 secs (for me, visually it is reasonable). Figure 2, of 2 secs of duration and notice the start of signals beta and gamma are noisy.

[image]
[image]

Taking in account EEG, I ask you,

1. is there any ideal time duration (min, or max)  of the signal to make band passing ?
2. Mi data has a duration of 22 minutes at 128 Hz of sampling, can I performed band pass of all the length or by small segments or windows?

I thank you in advance, please feel free to comment, I need to be right to extract features in the next step.